# I need help figuring what kind of tree/plant this is so i know how to care for it!

Tags: identification, trees

I think it is a tree of some sort and I was thinking maybe a money tree but the leaves seem to look different.

They seem rounder and they feel sort of waxy.

[image]

Comment: Appears to be a type of ficus plant   Perhpas ficus benjamina exotica or ficus elastica (rubber tree plant).   Did any of the store clerks have information on the plant?